# Can the union of a measurable set and a disjoint non-measurable set be measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $E$ is a measurable set and $A \subset E$, where $A$ is also measurable. Must it be the case that $E \backslash A$ is also measurable? If so, why?

Comment: Use properties of $\sigma$-algebras:$E\setminus A=E\cap A^c$

Comment: Moreover, the union of a measurable and a non-measurable set, can be measurable. Take for example ANY meadsurable set $A$ and ANY non-measurable set $N\subset A$. Then $A\cup N=A$.

Comment: Now, the disjoint union of a measurable and not-measurable set is NOT measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is **yes**. Just take a non-measurable subset of a measurable set.

The answer to the **different** question in the post is **yes**. This follows from the definition of $\sigma$-slgebras.

Comment: Ah yes, the title is poorly worded. I should have said "disjoint union". In which case it appears to be no.

Comment: For disjoint the answer is no... If you assume by contradiction that the answer is yes, you apply the definition of $\sigma$-algebras and you get that the non-measurable set is measurable.